# Get First Img link in bbcode C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, bbcode

how to get the first image ink in bbcode text in c#

i use this code for html but how to do that for bbcode

```
HtmlDocument document = new HtmlDocument();
document.LoadHtml(Model.TextSujet);
var imageUrl = (from image in document.DocumentNode.Descendants("img")
                where !String.IsNullOrEmpty(image.GetAttributeValue("src", null))
                select image.Attributes["src"].Value).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Sorry my bad I don't read the question correctly, thanks for pointing that out @codemonkey

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using a regex

```
        var regex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"\[img[^\]]*\]([^\[]*)");

        string text = @"Including an image
[img]http://www.bbcode.org/images/lubeck_small.jpg[/img]
Resizing the image
[img=100x50]http://www.bbcode.org/images/lubeck_small.jpg[/img]
Making the image clickable (in this case linking to the original image)
[url=http://www.bbcode.org/images/lubeck.jpg][img]http://www.bbcode.org/images/lubeck_small.jpg[/img][/url]
Resizing and adding meta information for the image";

        var match = regex.Match(text);

        if (match.Success)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1]);
        }
```